# Removing Conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, environment

I want to remove a certain environment created with conda. How can I achieve that? Let's say I have an active `testenv` environment. I tried, by following documentation, with:

```
$ conda env remove

CondaEnvironmentError: cannot remove current environment. deactivate and run conda remove again
```

I then deactivate it:

```
$ source deactivate
```

I try running again the command to remove it and I still get the same error. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Make sure you're running the terminal as an administrator otherwise commands will run successfully without throwing any error but env will not be removed.

Answer (score 1270):

You probably didn't fully deactivate the Conda environment - remember, the command you need to use with Conda is `conda deactivate` (for older versions, use `source deactivate`). So it may be wise to start a new shell and activate the environment in that before you try. Then deactivate it.

You can use the command

```
conda remove -n ENV_NAME --all
```

to remove the environment with that name. (`--name` is equivalent to `-n`)

Note that you can also place environments anywhere you want using `-p /path/to/env` instead of `-n ENV_NAME` when both creating and deleting environments, if you choose. They don't *have* to live in your conda installation.

**UPDATE, 30 Jan 2019**: From Conda 4.6 onwards the `conda activate` command becomes the new official way to activate an environment across all platforms. The changes are described in [this Anaconda blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/conda-4-6-release)

**UPDATE, 24 Feb 2023**: The `conda env` subcommand has been deprecated. Now, the [officially recommended](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment) way is `conda remove -n ENV_NAME --all`. You can update to the latest version with `conda install -n base -c defaults conda` (sometimes it helps to specify the new version with eg `... -c defaults conda=23.3.1`).

Comment: You're right, my mistake when writing the post. I meant `source deactivate`. Thank you

Comment: Actually you can use `conda deactivate` as well and it works likewise. At least in the version 4.4.11

Comment: Thanks. But not just `deactivate` on its own, right?

Comment: Yes, either `source deactivate` or `conda deactivate`

Comment: `EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /home/user/.conda/envs/ENVIRONMENT
`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and run this after you use `conda env remove`: `rm -rf ~/anaconda/envs/ENV_NAME` if you use the default anaconda install location.

Comment: If deleting an environment leaves anything behind I'd imagine that the Anaconda team would appreciate a bug report.

Comment: also if you create a prefix it will work: conda env remove -p << prefix path >>

Comment: What I did before was that I just removed the folder containing the virtual environment. Is it bad to the system integrity?

Comment: It's unlikely you'd mess anything up by removing the folder, but I'm a big fan of using recommended methods just in case anything changes.

Comment: why not describe in this answer what --all does?

Comment: If you're like me and remove conda environments to create space on the disk, remember to do a conda clean to delete cached packages after removing the environment, e.g.

`conda clean -a`

Read more here before doing it https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/clean.html

Comment: FYI: "Use --all flag to remove all packages **and** the environment itself.". Without it, you will only remove the packages. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html#conda-remove

Answer (score 292):

After making sure your environment is not active, type:

```
$ conda remove --name ENVIRONMENT --all
```

Comment: This is the information I needed. Would have been nice if `conda env --help` had given it.

Comment: `EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /home/user/.conda/envs/ENVIRONMENT
`

Comment: I submitted a bug about failures to update the help text, and it was marked as an easy issue for beginners, so there's hope of a fix.

Comment: What is the conda version that brought this command into existence? It din't work on conda 4.14.0 .

Answer (score 108):

[Official documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment) way worked for me:

```
conda remove --name myenv --all
```

Or just `conda env remove --name myenv`.

To verify that the environment was removed, in your terminal window or an Anaconda Prompt, run:

```
conda info --envs
```

The environments list that displays should not show the removed environment.

You anaconda3 enviroments folder might list an empty folder of deleted environment in your anaconda3 installation folder, like:

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs
```

Comment: What is the --all flag doing exactly? I couldn't find any docs for this

Answer (score 66):

If you are in **base**:

```
(base) HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-CMT:~$
```

remove **env_name** by:

```
conda env remove -n env_name
```

if you are already in **env_name** environment :

```
(env_name) HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-CMT:~$
```

deactivate then remove by :

```
conda deactivate
conda env remove -n env_name
```

Answer (score 52):

In my windows 10 Enterprise edition os this code works fine:
(suppose for environment namely testenv)

```
conda env remove --name testenv
```

Answer (score 48):

Environments created with the `--prefix` or `-p` flag must be removed with the `-p` flag (*not* `-n`).

For example: 
`conda remove -p </filepath/myenvironment> --all`, in which `</filepath/myenvironment>` is substituted with a complete or relative path to the environment.

Answer (score 37):

There're 3 ways to achieve this in total. Assuming you have a environment named `myenv`,

1. `conda env remove --name myenv`, `-n` is shortcut for `--name`.
2. `conda remove --name myenv --all`.
3. Delete the env folder directly. (Not recommended)

   ```sh
   # list environments and their locations
   conda env list
   # or
   # conda info --envs

   # delete the folder listed
   rm -rf /Users/username/.local/share/conda/envs/myenv
   ```

---

If you wanna delete the environment **without a prompt** to let you check again. Use `-y`, shortcut for `--yes`. (For global use check [silent prompt in conda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58148301/5101148))

```sh
conda env remove -n myenv -y
conda remove -n myenv --all -y
```

#### References

- `conda env --help`
- `conda remove --help`

Comment: And why is deleting the env folder directly not recommended? What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @NoName Conda provides packages with a hookable pre-unlink event fired prior to package removal. Deleting directly would skip this. AFAICT, it's rarely used and mostly manages things internal to the env (e.g., a Jupyter *extension* will de-register itself with the Jupyter instance through such hooks), so deleting everything shouldn't break stuff. However, [searching turns up some packages](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aconda-forge+unlink&type=code) (e.g., FSL-related packages) that appear to register externally, in which case manual deletion might leave dangling references.

Answer (score 32):

1. First deactivate the environment that you wish to remove.
2. Then type the following code:

   `conda env remove -n <your environment name>`
3. To make sure you have deleted it, you can use the following code.

   `conda info --envs`   or  `conda env list`

4.If you wan to remove all the dependencies along with the installed packages, you can use:

```
conda remove -n <environment name> --all
```

Comment: What is environment name and where i get it from please dont post half of the information. Your question should be complete

Answer (score 19):

You may try the following: Open anaconda command prompt and type

```
conda remove --name myenv --all
```

This will remove the entire environment.

Further reading: [docs.conda.io > Manage Environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment)

Answer (score 17):

To remove complete conda environment :

`conda remove --name YOUR_CONDA_ENV_NAME --all`

Answer (score 16):

My environment name is: test

```
conda remove -n test --all
```

Answer (score 16):

First you have to deactivate your environment before removing it. You can remove conda environment by using the following command

Suppose your environment name is "sample_env" , you can remove this environment by using

```
source deactivate    
conda remove -n sample_env --all
```

'--all' will be used to remove all the dependencies

Answer (score 12):

First I checkout from the environment (tensorflow):

```
conda deactivate
```

Then I removed the environment by:

```
conda remove -n tensorflow --all
```

> The tensorflow is the name of my environment

You can check your env name using this command:

```
conda env list
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `source deactivate` to deactivate the environment before removing it,  replace ENV_NAME with the environment you wish to remove:

```
source deactivate
conda env remove -n ENV_NAME
```

Comment: An explanation, what a code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Comment: `EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /home/user/.conda/envs/ENV_NAME`

Answer (score 7):

View the environments in Anaconda or miniconda:

```
conda env list
```

If you have created an environment using name then use:

```
conda remove -n envname --all
```

if you have created an environment using prefix then use:

```
conda remove -p [path] --all
```

Change the `envname` with your environment name and in case of prefix provide the complete `path` of the environment eg: `C:/Users/techv/Desktop/project/env`. 
`--all` will remove all the dependencies of the target environment.

I hope this answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

First deactivate the environment and come back to the base environment. From the base, you should be able to run the command `conda env remove -n <envname>`. This will give you the message

`Remove all packages in environment 
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\{envname}:`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
conda env remove --name tensorflow
```

Comment: Worked for me too. ```conda env remove --name <name of your environment>```


Later you can delete the environment folder from Anaconda or miniconda install location

```Anaconda\envs\<name of your environment>``` or ```Miniconda\envs\<name of your environment>```

Answer (score 4):

if you are unfamiliar with the command line , you can remove it using the anaconda dashboard

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Because you can only deactivate the active environment, so conda deactivate does not need nor accept arguments. The error message is very explicit here.

Just call conda deactivate
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7296#issuecomment-389504269

Answer (score -6):

on terminal it's showing

(base) [root@localhost ~]#

simply hit command :  conda deactivate

and you are out of conda env , now your prompt will look like

[root@localhost ~]#

Comment: The answer does not provide any new insights. It was already mentioned to run this command as root.