# Conda Environment duplication without downloading python

Tags: batch-file, yaml, anaconda, environment

I did a GUI application and my companny does not allow me to use .exe . Therefore, I have sent the project to shared folder and I created a .bat file to go that path and write python main.py. Hoewever, I need to make sure that everyone has the exact same environments as mine, I exported my env list as a .yml file but when I try to read it in my collegues computer, admin permission comes when it tries to download python (note that no one has python on their cmd, we use anaconda's python)
What do you guys recommend for me.

created bat file to import .yml file as an environment.

Comment: A different site. This one is for help with a code issue. It is not for assisting with how to set up a coding project or environment within your organization.

Comment: So what is the difference with this topic ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127834/removing-conda-environment?rq=2
do not get me wrong but If anyone knows the issue and understand my problem. They can simply reply

Comment: I take each question on its independent merits irrespective of whether moderators and/or other members of this community have allowed, disallowed, or answered similarly off topic questions here before. IMO, this particular question would be better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).