# skip installing confirm('yes' or 'no') in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, shell, docker, anaconda, dockerfile

Here's part of my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

#ubuntu:lastest

RUN apt-get update

COPY Anaconda3-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh /root/

WORKDIR /root/

RUN bash Anaconda3-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

RUN conda upgrade --all

...
```

during the installation process of Anaconda(bash Anaconda3-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh), there is a license needs agreement, which needs me to answer 'yes',

[install confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAjed.png)

but when it's run in dockerfile, it shows like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZANM.png),
like keep pressing ENTER, how can I skip this confirm or input 'yes'

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644612/conda-silently-installing-a-package?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Vico thanks dude, but not the same question

Comment: There is an anaconda image provided by continuumio on the Docker Hub here https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda/~/dockerfile/.
You can use this image, or you can check how they install in their Dockerfile. 

```RUN wget --quiet https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/anaconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/anaconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/anaconda.sh && \
    ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: @Mark thanks, I will try that

Comment: Agree that this is a different question. For other that stumble upon this later, the answer is `$ sh ancanda_installer.sh -b`  -- the `-b` is for "batch mode".